# How to iterate through an enmap?

Tags: discord.js, array.prototype.map, for-of-loop

I'm trying to iterate through an `enmap` for my discord.js bot, I've managed to set and get values from a single entry but I'm trying to set up a command that adds people to a newsletter like DM about minor major updates.

```js
if (args[0] === 'minor') {
  if (devlog.updates === 'minor') return message.channel.send('You are already recieving minor updates.').then(m => m.delete(5000))
  await client.devlog.set(userID, "yes", 'subscribed');
  await client.devlog.set(userID, "minor", 'updates');
  return message.channel.send('You will now recieve minor and major updates.').then(m => m.delete(5000))
}
if (args[0] === 'major') {
  if (devlog.updates === 'major') return message.channel.send('You are already recieving major updates.').then(m => m.delete(5000))
  await client.devlog.set(userID, "yes", 'subscribed');
  await client.devlog.set(userID, "major", 'updates');
  return message.channel.send('You will now recieve only major updates.').then(m => m.delete(5000))
}
if (!args[0]) {
  if (devlog.subscribed === 'yes') {
    await client.devlog.set(userID, "no", 'subscribed');
    await client.devlog.set(userID, "none", 'updates');
    return message.channel.send('You will stop recieving updates about RoboTurtle all together').then(m => m.delete(5000))
  }
  if (devlog.subscribed === 'no') {
    return message.channel.send(`Please choose wether you\'d like to recieve minor or major updates! (minor has both) **devlog minor/major**`).then(m => m.delete(10000))
  }
}
```

It kind of works but it won't trigger the message if they already are subscribed to the same type of update and if they do just `!devlog` it's meant to either set them to not receive updates if they already are, or tell them to choose between the two if they aren't, however it just sends the last message either way.

I tried setting up my `enmap` iteration for DMing all subscribed people with a `for...of` function based off the `.map` related docs (since they're meant to be just "fancier" maps) but to no avail, since they don't really show discord style use cases.

```js
if (args[0] === 'minor') {
  for (let entry of client.devlog) {
    if (entry.updates === 'minor') {
      let user = client.users.get(entry)
      user.send(`**[Minor Update]\n${args.slice(1)}`)
    }
  }
}
if (args[0] === 'major') {
  for (let entry of client.devlog) {
    if (entry.subscribed === 'yes') {
      let user = client.users.get(entry)
      user.send(`**[Major Update!]\n${args.slice(1)}`)
    }
  }
}
```

In case anyone wanted to look at the full code to get a better idea of what Im trying to do here ya go: https://pastebin.com/bCML6EQ5

Comment: You said that your're using an `enmap` in Discord: does it mean that you're using a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) (from wich enmaps have been created) or simply it means that you're using a normal `enamp`?

Comment: Normal enmap, and I didn't know where to put this but thought it might be useful if someone has the same issue..

`if (!client.devlog.userID) await client.devlog.set(userID, defaultDevlog);`
had to be
`if (!client.devlog.get(userID)) await client.devlog.set(userID, defaultDevlog);`
for the part of my code that kept sending the wrong message, it was actually sending the right one, it just couldn't find the enmap entry and created a default one (then executed the code) long story short make sure you .get your enmaps! xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are just an extension of the normal `Map` class, I would iterate through them with [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach):

```js
let yourEnmap = new Enmap();
yourEnmap.set('user_id', 'your_values');

yourEnmap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  ...
});
```

In your case it would be something like:

```js
client.devlog.forEach((values, user_id) => {
  // you can check your subscription here, the use the user_id to send the DM
  client.users.get(user_id).send("Your message.");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that, exactly what I needed, I had no clue how to set up either for...of or forEach loops, I slightly understand forEach more now thanks to you :)

Do you have any idea why my other part is sending the messages it shouldn't? Is there a different approach I could take? Only if you know its a simple fix otherwise don't worry :)